# I tried converting the tuples in a list of tuples using range and code worked but when i tried the same using 'for i in list:' it is not working:

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
lst = [(8, 7), (9, 6), (4, 8), (3, 5), (9, 4)]

for i in range(len(lst)):
    lst[i] = list(lst[i])
```

this is working fine.

```
for i in lst:
    i = list(i)
```

but this is not working. I don't know why ? Can anyone please tell me the reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for [`Mutable Sequence Types`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) such as `list` explain assignment of an object `x` to an item at index `i` within a sequence `s` as follows:

> **Operation**: `s[i] = x`
>
> **Result**: item `i` of `s` is replaced by `x`

This means that the line in your code reading `lst[i] = list(lst[i])` will replace item `i` of `lst` with `list(lst[i]))`, which is a newly created `list` containing the elements of the `tuple` referenced by `lst[i]`.

In contrast, consider your code reading:

```py
for i in lst:
    i = list(i)
```

The `for` statement assigns the item at index 0 of `lst` to the variable `i` and executes the statement `i = list(i)`, then on its next iteration assigns the item at index 1 of `lst` to `i` and again executes the statement `i = list(i)`, and so forth until `lst` has been exhausted.

Note that:

- the assignment to the variable `i` by the for loop causes `i` to be a reference to an item in `lst`
- because every item in `lst` is originally a `tuple`, and because `tuple` is an [`immutable sequence type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#immutable-sequence-types), there is no way to change the object referenced by `i` and hence no way to change `lst` using `i`

  - **Interesting side note**: If `lst` were a list of lists (instead of a list of tuples), then we *would* be able to modify an item of `lst` using `i`, for example as follows:

  ```py
  lst = [[8, 7], [9, 6], [4, 8], [3, 5], [9, 4]]
  for i in lst:
      i[:] = i + [0]
      i.append(1)
  print(lst)

  # Output:
  [[8, 7, 0, 1], [9, 6, 0, 1], [4, 8, 0, 1], [3, 5, 0, 1], [9, 4, 0, 1]]
  ```
- `list(i)` creates a new object of type `list` from the tuple `i`
- `i = list(i)` assigns that new object to the variable `i`, so that `i` is now a reference to the newly created `list` object; the object that `i` previously referenced, namely the `tuple` item in `lst`, remains intact as an item of `lst`.

Answer (score 1):

In the second option you just assign `list(i)` to the name `i`, then do nothing with it until it is overwritten in the next loop.

An alternative:

```
lst[:] = list(map(list, lst))

print(lst)
```

output: `[[8, 7], [9, 6], [4, 8], [3, 5], [9, 4]]`

Answer (score 1):

In your first code

```py
for i in range(len(lst)):
    lst[i] = list(lst[i])
```

`lst[i]` is a variable which directly point to the element in list. Hence, any change in it effects the list itself.

Whereas in your second code

```py
for i in lst:
    i = list(i)
```

`i` is a variable used in for loop and is not pointing to the list `lst`. Hence, any change to id doesn't affect the `lst`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing in the first code is,`lst[i] = list(lst[i])` putting the value of the converted list in the index of the list whereas in your second code you are just assigning that converted list to `i`

you can try this:

```
lst = [(8, 7), (9, 6), (4, 8), (3, 5), (9, 4)]
lst = [list(i) for i in lst]
```